# Multiple mandatory fields in a form

Tags: forms

I have a form with 2 mandatory fields, but once one is filled the other is not required. Means the user can select which one of these fields he wishes to fill. 
The fields order in the form is not fixed, means the user can modify it and reorder, so these 2 fields are not next to each other (and I can't force them to be).

How can I indicate that these 2 fields are mandatory but the user can select between them? if I mark both of them as mandatory (e.g. color in Red) the user may think he actually need to fill both while that's not really required?

Tnx in advance!

Comment: Do you validate the filled one before the other becomes optional? How are you indicating "required" (/ "optional"?) right now?

Comment: Not really. One field is free text while the other is a selection from pre-set options. Yes, I indicate which fields are required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context these are some suggestions:

- Indicate explicitly in the Label of both options that either this or the other is required.
- You could make use of a third setting (a radio button or a dropdown) to select which of these the user wants to fill.

If there is any chance you could provide some image or real case information (or similar example) it might be easier to give a more specific solution.

Comment: Tnx for this, I guess that a label for both will do. A radio button or dropdown is not possible. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome :) I am not sure how valid are these solutions for your case, but I'm glad if they helped.