# How to show Either user can select one of the field from two or both the fields?

Tags: required-fields

I have a situation in my design where I have to show the two fields mandatory
Conditions are 1) Either User can select both fields
2) User can select any one of the two fields

Please help me.

1. Should  I put asterisk on both
2. Should I use "or" in between two fields
3. Should I use check box for each fields

It is not possible to show group of two fields in my scenario.

Comment: you have a mock? it's more helpful to show us your thinking so far

Comment: No, I do not have the mockups now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple mandatory fields in a form](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104699/multiple-mandatory-fields-in-a-form)

Comment: What are the 2 fields called?